# Select only Time in Datetime Widget Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to show the widget time in the Datetime field, and that this value is stored in the variable hor_ini is currently declared as follows:

```
hor_ini = fields.Datetime (required = True)
```

but I do not achieve that when I select the view fields show me  for default only the time widget

[image]

Any suggestions, is welcome

Comment: Click on the calendar icon just above the time selection and you should show the calendar selection widget.

Comment: Hello @QuentinTHEURET I need that show me only time widget for default

Comment: You can do one thing use datetime filed and just apply time while writing that field.  For this you need to import time lib and write time in your datetime field.

Answer (score 2):

Change your date field to **float** in python.

In xml, add **widget="float_time"**

Comment: I suggest you link to some documentation for this since it is not entirely obvious how those types of fields work.

Comment: in odoo 15, this solution is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try widget='time' in the XML View definition ?